# I can not find sql server library (cordova-plugin-sqlserver)

Tags: sql-server, cordova, ionic-framework

I installed the cordova-plugin-sqlserver library in the following address.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-sqlserver

But I do not know how to import it into the project.

Eg.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { BaglantiProvider } from '../../providers/baglanti/baglanti';
import { SqlServer } from 'what shall i write ???????? ';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public baglanti : BaglantiProvider) {
  }
  test(){
    SqlServer.init("192.168.0.120", "SQLEXPRESS", "sa", "01234567", "dinademo", function(event) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(event));
    }, function(error) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you installed the plugin correctly (`ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/SergioDosSantos/cordova-plugin-sqlserver.git`
), you should have access to the object via a global variable called `SqlServer`. You cannot import it as a module.

Because there is not type definition for that object you cannot call it directly (like `window.SqlServer`): TypeScript will complain that it doesn't exist.

You must at least declare it first (above the `@Component` decorator):

```
declare var SqlServer: any;
```

Now you can use it in your component but you will not benefit from TypeScript: no completion, no checking. For that you would have to create a type definition file.

Answer (score 0):

the correct way to reference it from inside the code is:

`(<any>window).SqlServer`

Answer (score 0):

1) Inside your project, open "config.xml". This will bring you to a tab with options down the side (see image below for reference).

Use the side option "Plugins", then click "Custom" out of the "Core / Custom / Installed" pages.

2) Select "Git" as your method to retrieve the plugin - it may ask you to install git, just install as normal - you'll need to save your project and close down visual studio in order to install it. Once it's finished, open your project and browse to the same location.

This time, you'll see the option "Enter a Git repository location for the plugin you want to install", as seen in the image below.

Enter this URL:

> https://github.com/SergioDosSantos/cordova-plugin-sqlserver.git

Click the little arrow button to the right hand side of the textbox "-->" and it will install the plugin.

Image of the screen after a successful installation:-

[image]