# Import on ionic 2+ SqlServer is not defined (cordova-plugin-sqlserver)

Tags: sql-server, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I need to add the [cordova-plugin-sqlserver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-sqlserver) to communicate directly to sql server. I found 2 solutions but non of them fix the "SqlServer is not defined" error. I had tried the both solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47811266/i-can-not-find-sql-server-library-cordova-plugin-sqlserver/50622769#50622769)
but didnt fixed

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
 declare var SqlServer: any;  

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
     this.test() 

  }

     test(){ 
      SqlServer.init("127.0.0.1", "sql_server_ii", "sa", "123456", "asMainCoif", function(event) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(event));
    }, function(error) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    });
  }
}
```

and it returns me this error (the plugin was installed correctly)

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: SqlServer is not defined
ReferenceError: SqlServer is not defined
    at HomePage.webpackJsonp.193.HomePage.test (home.ts:17)
    at new HomePage (home.ts:12)
    at createClass (core.js:12481)
    at createDirectiveInstance (core.js:12326)
    at createViewNodes (core.js:13784)
    at createRootView (core.js:13673)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15098)
    at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (core.js:14381)
    at ComponentFactory_.create (core.js:11278)
    at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (core.js:4030)
    at HomePage.webpackJsonp.193.HomePage.test (home.ts:17)
    at new HomePage (home.ts:12)
    at createClass (core.js:12481)
    at createDirectiveInstance (core.js:12326)
    at createViewNodes (core.js:13784)
    at createRootView (core.js:13673)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15098)
    at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (core.js:14381)
    at ComponentFactory_.create (core.js:11278)
    at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (core.js:4030)
    at c (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.reject (polyfills.js:3)
    at NavControllerBase._fireError (nav-controller-base.js:223)
    at NavControllerBase._failed (nav-controller-base.js:216)
    at nav-controller-base.js:263
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:4760)
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.run (polyfills.js:3)
    at polyfills.js:3
```